# Posting on game activity feed

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Is there any way to post on a user's activity feed for an iOS game? There seems to be no API for this but there is a permission

```
user_games_activity
```

on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms

I have noticed that there are activity feeds for Facebook games itself, but I haven't come across an activity feed regarding an iOS app.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post user actions/achivements from iOS by taking `publish_actions` extended permission, but you need backend server support. You need a public url with open graph tags for each object/achievement.

[Publish actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms)

> Allows your app to publish to the Open Graph using Built-in Actions,
>   Achievements, Scores, or Custom Actions. Your app can also publish
>   other activity which is detailed in the Publishing Permissions doc.
>   Note: The user-prompt for this permission will be displayed in the
>   first screen of the Enhanced Auth Dialog and cannot be revoked as part
>   of the authentication flow. However, a user can later revoke this
>   permission in their Account Settings. If you want to be notified if
>   this happens, you should subscribe to the permissions object within
>   the Realtime API.

If you want to post achivements, here is basic info. For more info see the below link.

> The Graph API for achievements allows game developers to publish user
>   achievements in their game to provide more meaningful and relevant
>   stories.
>
> Note: This API is only available to applications categorized as
>   'Games'. You can categorize your app as 'Games' in the Developer app
>   by navigating to About > Basic Info and selecting 'Games` in the drop
>   down menu in the category field.

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/

FYI: [Improving app distrubution](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/21/improving-app-distribution-on-ios/)